# Can't get scene stylesheet from css

Tags: css, javafx, scene

src/test/java
 com.whatever.ui.docking
 
        DockingConsoleDemo.java
        dockingconsole.css

```
public class DockingConsoleDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        DockingConsoleController controller = new DockingConsoleController();
        Scene scene = new Scene(controller, 800, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/com/whatever/ui/docking/dockingconsole.css");
...
```

After executing:
 
com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
 
WARNING: Resource "/com/whatever/ui/docking/dockingconsole.css" not found.

Hot to build correct path to css file?

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a URL specification. Try

```
String cssLocation = "/com/whatever/ui/docking/dockingconsole.css" ;
URL cssURL = getClass().getResource(cssLocation);
scene.getStylesheets().add(cssURL.toExternalForm());
```

You can log the URL and check it's looking in the right place. Also make sure the css file is being deployed to the same location as your class files (bin directory, or wherever, depending on your IDE and setup).

Comment: You mean dockingconsole.css must be in the same package where DockingConsoleDemo.java is?

Comment: Assuming `DockingConsoleDemo` is in `com.whatever.ui.docking`, yes. But my point was to make sure that is true after compilation, not just in the source directory hierarchy.